# I want to convert yolov5 to TFLite type and perform object detection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, yolo, yolov5

As the title says, I am trying to convert yolov5 to TFLite and perform object detection using the converted model, but I am stumped.
I am wondering if the conversion of the model is correct to begin with, so let me ask you a question.

I have followed the steps below to convert to TFLite.
Also, the execution was done at GoogleColaboratory.

1. clone from GitHub (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git)
2. install using requirements.txt
3. convert to TFLite with the following command

`python export.py --weights yolov5m.pt --img 640 --include tflite`

As a result of the execution, the following tflite format file was created.

`/content/yolov5/yolov5m-fp16.tflite`

Are there any problems so far?

Here is a summary of the commands I wrote this time.

```
!git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.git
%cd yolov5/
!pip install -r requirements.txt
!python export.py --weights yolov5m.pt --img 640 --include tflite
```

I ran the following code for inference, but I get an error in the

> interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_tensor)

section.

The errors are as follows.

> ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Got value of type UINT8 but expected
> type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: serving_default_input_1:0

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import tensorflow as tf
import time

# model_load
model_path = '/content/yolov5/yolov5m-fp16.tflite'
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

image = Image.open('/content/picture1.jpg').resize((640, 640))
input_tensor = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
input_tensor = np.expand_dims(input_tensor, axis=0

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_tensor)
interpreter.invoke()
```

So far, the contents of the tflite file are also well contained.
However, when I try to use it to do object detection, I am getting my hands full with lots of errors.
I would appreciate it if you could provide a site or source code that might be helpful.

Comment: Please add what ever errors you are getting to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have added the code and error text.